# Encoding and decoding a cypher bytes variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode, encode

I'm trying to send a variable with a cypher which at the beginning is a byte type variable but then I have to convert it to string and then back to byte.

```
b'j\xd7cv2/\t\xb5\x9d0\x9bh\xf6\xbd\x08\xd4a\xc2)\x1d\xd4\xae\xa8\xfd\xe9\xe9\xb2\xe9\xa9\x87\x1e\x97.\xf1LT\xf9\xf6\xba[\xab\x10\xab\x98\xf8\x81\xd4\xd9!D\xe1.\x9a\xbcG\xab"\xec\x05}9{\xee\x82=\xb2\x1f5a\xb9\xfd\xcbE}\x1d[\xd3_z\xaf\x1a\xcc\xbc\xfdQ\xde\xbe\xbd\xe8\xe3\xcd\x0e\xa2\xc6\x1a\x9f\x18\x12G\xb2\xa8g\xbfK\x8a\x0e\xf6\xf5)y\xbc6\x03Z^|\xf5\xf1\t\x9dk\xefUo6\xd7\x05\xc7\xef\x941\r\x02\xfb\xc1_\x19/\xea\x81\xb64s\xc7\x92\xbf\x1aL\xff\'\xb6\x87o\xd0\\\x90\x98\xadn.\x02g\xa0\xde\x1b\xcem`)7Hf\x9fn*Kq\xa6ee\x8b\xfc\x88\xee+\xa6\x18#c\x1aE\xd3\xbcw\xabT\xa33*\xd8b\xc5\x90=H\xe0\x02\xb0>P=%\x91\xa5\x98M\xa5\x04\xfd\xa8\xa3R\xc0)+\xa6K\xf9\x9c\xb1\xd1\xf4\xf8J\xf5\xe1W7\xde\xbd7\xc59\xcc\xb3J\xe2\xd5l\xdbZ\xa3*\xa2Q4'
```

I already have tried to covert it to base64 and to utf-8

now i have this code:

```
type(cipher)
> bytes
cipher = str(cipher)
cipher.decode()
str.encode(cipher)
```

> this returns me bytes but diferent from the original

```
b'b\'Z@\\xa0\\xa9\\x05\\xad"\\xa6,\\xe8\\xa4\\xa0*\\xbe\\x0e\\xd3Y\\xb9g\\xbb#\\x97\\xe2\\x9b&\\x8b\\xc0\\x8d\\xb8[Z\\xce\\rm\\xc7\\xe0^\\x0cJm\\xf0y?\\xd8\\xb2\\xc5+$\\x05_\\xa33\\xe7Q\\x82\\xa5E\\xb6\\x0f\\x18\\xd9\\xbf\\x08\\xe7\\xd0vG$}w\\xc4 \\xe4\\xf8*\\x0eR\\xd3\\xda\\x12\\x95\\xd2\\x1cJ3\\x02,#\\xfe\\x17\\x02\\xc9\\xb8\\xdcdt\\xfb\\xa1\\xc6\\xf6\\xe4\\x129\\xfd\\xe1U\\xf9\\xb9\\xa1j\\x08\\xb3\\xbe{\\xf9\\xfd\\x9bji\\xa7\\xea0\\xe8G\\xde_@\\x90\\x07Q\\x8b\\xfblQUd\\x1bhGv\\xbck\\x8bS\\xdc3\\x83L\\xa1dA\\xe6Mi\\n\\x92y\\xd4\\xe1\\xf9\\xe5\\x86\\x9cg\\xe7e \\x9bp\\x8f\\x1f\\xe9W|\\xf4\\xaf\\xcd\\xfa\\xd1\\xf3\\xdd\\xd5\\x83\\x87\\x04<\\xfc\\x1ch\\x99wG5\\xd2\\xb2\\xd8~\\xc7dd\\x9fZFGe\\xef\\xdf\\x90W\\xef\\x01\\x03\\xd7\\xc6=\\n\\xe3\\xdbQV2H\\xa57\\xa5\\xf6n`\\x0b\\xb4K\\x90g2\\xc6\\xb8P\\x12\\xce\\xff\\x9a\\xcb\\x94\\xae\\xf3\\x9a\\x8a\\x9e\\xb8^\\xa4\\xa1\\x84\\xfc\\x07$\''
```

converting from bytes to utf-8 gives me this error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 3: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert bytes to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Comment: Calling `str` on a `bytes` instance doesn't decode it to `str` - you need to call the `bytes` instance's `decode` method - see the duplicate target.

Comment: @snakecharmerb it doesn't work decoding with utf-8 -> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 3: invalid continuation byte

Comment: If the bytes are the enciphered text then they will need to be deciphered before decoding.  Or maybe they are encoded with some other encoding.  There isn't enough information to know.

Comment: Echoing @snakecharmerb.  You should not try to arbitrarily convert bytes to str without knowing and/or specifying an encoding.  The bytes are just jumbled 1s and 0s without an encoding attached to them.